# NX Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, angular-devkit

After upgrading the NX version of my Angular app from `15.6.3` to `15.9.2`.

Initially I got some failures which I solved by getting rid of `angular.json` and makings some changes to my libs' `project.json` to make it work, however, it now fails with:

> NX   Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'

What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by rolling back my changes and upgrading using `nx migrate nx@15.9.2` which took care of the missing parts.